# ? Appearing instead of ₹ in CMD

Tags: c#, .net

I am learning C# and I was making a rupee to $$ converter, although I have fonts installed on my machine to be able to support ₹ this character, the command prompt terminal shows a '?' I have no idea what this is, but help would be nice. I use .NET Core 5.0.102, I also have the [fonts needed to support this character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/fontsupport.htm)

Screenshots:
[image: Terminal and Visual Studio Screenshot]

Comment: but..... have you _configured the console_ to use this font?

Comment: It's the terminal not supporting the character... does `echo ₹` work... I just tested and can confirm that it works in windows terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixes your issue.
Encode you console output in UTF-8 format.

Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

```
namespace stack
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            Console.WriteLine("₹");
        }
    }
}
```